# Loading HDF5 model in Python (Keras TF backened) is very slow

Tags: python-3.x, performance, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I am very new to Keras. I have five saved models (via tensorflow backend) and when I load them with (load_model) it takes more than 20 seconds for each model to load. I tried to make the process parallel so that each model_load could be processed by different core. Here what I have tried:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(processes=5)
pool.map(loadf, (filename for filename in ['model1.h5', 'model2.h5','model3.h5','model4.h5','model5.h5']))
pool.close()
```

And it throws the error below:

```
...

TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(43, 80), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

How can I make those 5 models to be loaded separately in different cores?